# How to parse keyboard information read by sshd processes using the read system call

Tags: linux

When I use the "trace" command to trace the read system call of an ssh process, I get the results shown in the picture. I would like to parse the keyboard keys that correspond to these results.[using "trace" command picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwVAs.png)

Comment: For once - that's impossible. You could have typed anything from your keyboard, including unprintable and strange characters. But practically: extract the strings from the output, write a program to convert octal sequences into real bytes, write a parser (only parser) for ANSI escape sequences for current terminal, remove them from the strings and what's left is the input. Please post what have you tried, what research did you do, what did you started with, what exactly are you having problem with? I still prefer `strace -x` for hex output, easier for me to read.

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures of text - please post the text as text into the question instead. And please if you are searching for someone to write some code for you, I suggest freelancing site. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).